# How to Fill effect Text Box in Word Document using c#?

Tags: c#

I want to insert text from **TextBox** in a word document using **c#** and **spire.dll**  tools, but when I using code `FillEffects` not worked same this code

```
 textBox.Format.FillEfects.Gradient.Color1 = Color.Red;
 textBox.Format.FillEfects.Gradient.Color2 = Color.Yellow;
 textBox.Format.FillEfects.Gradient.ShadingStyle = GradientShadingStyle.DiagonalUp;
```

The code is correct and my program is build correct, but it not make any changes for **textBox** and if I  want to fill effect with picture it not worked else Like this code

```
textBox.Format.FillEfects.Picture = pictureBox1.Image;
```

I Attach To you My small project to see why this code not worked

Answer (score 0):

Okay after trying to fix this for a few hours i figured it out. I have slightly re-coded your textbox but don't worry. I added comments. I worked hard on this one. The answer though, was quite simple. I have never used Spire so I had to learn as I went.

```
//Creates gradient
Spire.Doc.BackgroundGradient myGradient = new BackgroundGradient();
myGradient.Color1 = Color.Red;
myGradient.Color2 = Color.Yellow;
myGradient.ShadingStyle = GradientShadingStyle.DiagonalUp;
myGradient.ShadingVariant = GradientShadingVariant.ShadingDown;           

//Insert TextBox
Paragraph paragraph1 = section.AddParagraph();
Spire.Doc.Fields.TextBox textBox = paragraph1.AppendTextBox(200, 100);
textBox.Format.LineColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
textBox.Format.LineWidth = 3.5F;
textBox.Format.LineStyle = TextBoxLineStyle.Double;
//Sets the gradient you made
textBox.Format.FillEfects.Gradient = myGradient;
//Sets the textbox to USE the gradient
textBox.Format.FillEfects.Type = BackgroundType.Gradient;
```

Comment: I want you To click on this link it's contain my Project and see it               http://www.4shared.com/rar/jkZqHHdqce/WindowsFormsApplication5.html

Comment: In fact i want to use gradient color in word doument by c#

Comment: You are Excellent And inelegant Programmer Thank you  Rynoh97   and i want to ask you another Question i want to make  ID Card maker with c# how can i export all data  like Barcode and Image in coordinated  Word Document and if you have Open Source It Ok Thank's Again

Comment: @user3672511 do you have the project folder i can go off of. Have you started the project already? So i don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: No i Don't Have my folder But it easy to make but first collect all data to make it easy I want to Make Id Card Maker for data base and Design No Problem But How Can i Export All Data Like Personal Image and Logo And Signature and Barcode to Word Document and Coordinated to Edit it If Want And print like this image so What I Use crystal report Or What?  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hvdwh.jpg

Comment: @user3672511 You are probably going to want to create a table with rows and columns to place your data in and have a bakcground image of the actually style of the card.

Comment: Mark question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code to your program before setting the textBox fill effect.

```
 textBox.Format.FillEfects.Type = BackgroundType.Gradient;
```

E-iceblue Support team.